# discord.js way to put a limit on what the bot reads

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I run the command and my bot takes the code it reads what is In front of it, please help

```
    let sentence = message.content.split("2");
    sentence.shift();
    sentence = sentence.join(" ");
    

    let input = message.content.split("1");
    input.shift();
    // Made a variable that removes what comes before
    // it but cant figure it out to stop reading what is before
    input = input.join(" ");
    

    (message.channel.send(sentence));
    (message.channel.send(input))
```

essentially bot does this

*MAE 1test 2no

bot,
no
test 2no
please help

this is my first time making a question on stack overflow so it might be rough.
thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! I have not quite understood what you're trying to do. But I'll try my best, so please comment below if I'm getting anything wrong.
It *seems* like you're trying to delete the first part of a command, which is the prefix, to get the command itself.
Here's how I'd have done that.

```js
const prefix = "abc!"
const msgContent = "abc!help"

const command = msgContent.substr(prefix.length)

console.log(command)
```

If you're trying to get what's between `1` and `2`:

```js
const startChar = "1"
const endChar = "2"

const messageContent = "blahblah1hello2blahblah"

const command = messageContent.match(/(1)*([a-z])*2/)[0].slice(1, -1)

console.log(command)
```

Comment: thank you, making a variable is a great idea to use

Comment: Did it work? If so, could you mark my answer as accepted? If not, explain a little bit more what's your problem by editing your question?